# How to add text on jprogressbar?

Tags: java, swing, desktop, jtextfield, jprogressbar

I am using a jprogressbar to indicate the availability status.
 **i want to display a text of 40%[assumption] inside the progressbar**.
 how to do it? the text was changed according to the availability value

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use:

Initialising:

```
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
```

Updating:

```
progressBar.setValue(newValue);
```

Comment: No need for this line: progressBar.setString(newValue + "%");

Comment: The setString line may be helpful to include for people who want to display something other than a percentage. It helped me :)

Answer (score 4):

- Use `setStringPainted(true)` to show the **Percentage** of work completed.
- Use `setValue()` which will help setting the **incremental value** and `setString()` to display the **end message** when done...

**Here is an example from my code base :**

```
final JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0 , 100);  // 0 - min , 100 - max
bar.setStringPainted(true);
panel.add(bar);                   // panel is a JPanel's Obj reference variable

JButton butt = new JButton("start");
butt.addActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(){
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                int x = 0;
                while(x<=100) {
                    x++;
                    bar.setValue(x);        // Setting incremental values
                    if (x ==  100 ){
                        bar.setString("Its Done");   // End message
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep(200);
                        }catch(Exception ex){ }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: better, confortable and easiest that SwingWorker

Answer (score 3):

- > I am using a jprogressbar to indicate the availability status.

  please read [tutorial about JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html)
- > i want to display a text of 40%[assumption] inside the progressbar.

  [Using Determinate Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) in the JProgressBar tutorial
- > how to do it? the text was changed according to the availability value

  more in the [SwingWorker tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

This will show the progress inside the bar

```
   progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows the progress percentage inside the progress bar

```
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear if your `[assumption]` is part of the string you want displayed. If so, the complete solution would be something like:

```
private static final String PROGRESS_MASK = "%d%% [assumption]";

public void someMethod() {
  ...

  progressBar.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
      progressBar.setString(String.format(PROGRESS_MASK,
        progressBar.getValue()));
    }
  }

  progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
}
```

... as you would be unable to rely on the default string which merely displays the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should notice here. Those are,

1) You have to set paintString  variable of JProgressBar using setStringPainted method. You can do that like

> jprogressBar.setStringPainted(true)

you have to do this because,

> isStringPainted()

method should return true, if the progress bar has to show the values or percentage of progress on it.

2) Now to customize with your custom value, set the your custom on jprogressBar instance using

> jprogressBar.setString(customString)

then  it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tutorial link which shows how to set the value (i.e. 10%  or 40%...) according to the status of the progress bar http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html