# Creating a bar with HTML in a JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I want to create a JLabel that has some text. Behind the text there should be a bar. The width of the bar should depend upon some external parameters. Is it possible to to this with the basic HTML support of JLabels?

[Mockup](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3167/vf9tvihp_jpg.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, but I would not go that way, I would use a `JProgressBar` to create that bar, because it even supports a string painted over it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776506/how-to-add-text-on-jprogressbar) for more details.

In short:

```
// Do this when initializing:
yourProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);

// When you want to update it:
yourProgressBar.setValue(theCurrentValueAsInt);
yourProgressbar.setString(theCurrentValueAsString); // That can be any string.
```