# how to keep JLabel over JProgressbar

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

This is a part of my java code, in this code I want that the progress bar should always remains under the label (at the back of label), progress bar is under the label when I start the program, but progress bar comes over/upon the label when I click the button and start progress. So please tell how can I keep the label always over the progress bar???

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;


public class Test {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.VERTICAL,0,100);
    JButton button = new JButton();

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        label.setBounds(100,100,100,50);
        bar.setBounds(140,25,20,200);
        button.setBounds(220,100,50,50);
        button.addActionListener(new Progress());
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(bar);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Progress extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> implements ActionListener {

        public Void doInBackground() {
            for(int i=0; i<101; i++) {
                bar.setValue(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            this.execute();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't use null layout. Learn and use layout managers.

Comment: Why do you need to do it this way?  Can't you use [`JProgressBar#setStringPainted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setStringPainted(boolean)) instead?  Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why would people ever consider using a tool the way it was designed to be used? What a revelation...

Comment: is there no way to solve my problem keeping null layout???

Comment: @MadProgrammer Blame Oracle for this. They introduce absolute positioning in their tutorials, which had me using it for a while due to simplicity. Even though they recommend using a LayoutManager, they really shouldn't have introduced it, let alone allow it

Comment: @MirzaGhalib In reality, no. If using null layout, theres nothing forcing the label to stay within the progress bar (since you aren't placing components relative to other components) . Even if you were to get it working on your computer (through percise placing of components), the results could vary on other platforms

Comment: @MirzaGhalib You could apply a layout manager to the `JProgressBar` and add the `JLabel` to it...there's some other problems, but it's doable...but I don't see why...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I posted up my answer what do you think? :)

Comment: @MirzaGhalib I posted my answer please me lemee know how it went

Comment: @KickButtowski I'm still trying to work out what's wrong with [`JProgressBar#setStringPainted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setStringPainted(boolean))

Comment: @MadProgrammer cool so lemme later what you think about my answer thank you :) your opinion is ** Google stock market** lol

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do what you are, when `JProgressBar` already provides the means to display a `String` value...

See [`JProgressBar#setStringPainted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setStringPainted(boolean)) for more details...

[image: Progress]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ProgressBarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgressBarTest();
    }

    public ProgressBarTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {            
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();
                pb.setValue(0);
                pb.setStringPainted(true);
                pb.setString("Look ma, no hands");
                frame.add(pb);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                            int progress = (int)Math.round((index / 1000f) * 100);
                            setProgress(progress);
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                            int value = (int) evt.getNewValue();
                            System.out.println(value);
                            pb.setValue(value);
                        }
                    }
                });

                worker.execute();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Updated**

Now, if you "really" want to put a label on top of a progress bar, there are some tricks you can do, for example...

[image: Progress]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ProgressBarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgressBarTest();
    }

    public ProgressBarTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JLabel label = new JLabel("I feel the need for speed");
                JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.weightx = 1;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                gbc.ipady = 20;

                frame.add(pb, gbc);

                gbc.weightx = 0;
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
                gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 5, 0);
                frame.add(label, gbc);


                frame.add(pb, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                            int progress = (int) Math.round((index / 1000f) * 100);
                            setProgress(progress);
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                            int value = (int) evt.getNewValue();
                            System.out.println(value);
                            pb.setValue(value);
                        }
                    }
                });

                worker.execute();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Basically, this places both the label and progress bar at the same location within the `GridBagLayout`...

Comment: I think you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416336/jprogressbar-setstringpaintedtrue-is-painting-two-strings question

Comment: the op asks how to keep JLabel over JProgressbar

Comment: @KickButtowski I know what the OP asks for, I'm asking why when `JProgressBar` already supports it.  When the OP says "over", they mean "ontop off", look at the bounds they are using, the progress bar will cover the label...;)

Comment: @KickButtowski  See also [Is “Don't do it” a valid answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8891/155831) (yes) & [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831) (this so far, is an XY problem).

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry I didn't get ur point. it seems I got this question all wrong

Comment: *"I feel the need for speed"*  "I feel the nafety for safety" (Leela).

Comment: @KickButtowski  You read both those questions, as well as at least the accepted answers, in less than a minute?  Try reading them again, more slowly.  Also, be more specific about what you don't understand.  I do not intend writing a novel to explain each link I offer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I changed my answer could you lemme know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post and idea that @MadProgrammer gave me

```
"You can use:

Initialising:

progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
Updating:

progressBar.setValue(newValue);
progressBar.setString(newValue + "%");"
```

Source of this answer :

[How to add text on jprogressbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776506/how-to-add-text-on-jprogressbar)

My answer to this problem is

Code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100);
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {


        bar.setStringPainted(true);
        bar.setString("I am a JProgressBar and ready to go here");
        button.addActionListener(new Progress());

        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;

        pane.add(bar, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        pane.add(button, c);

        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class Progress extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
                bar.setValue(i);
                bar.setString(Integer.toString(i) + "%");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            this.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]
[image]

Comment: <cough>bar.setBounds<cough>.  Also, you are violating the sing thread rules of Swing by updating the progress bar outside of the EDT

Comment: what you mean <cough>bar.setBounds<cough>?

Comment: You've just told the OP not to use `null` layout and while I know you're not, you've then called `setBounds` on a non-window component...

Comment: @MadProgrammer how do you make the gif ?

Comment: I use a tool called [LICECap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/), I like to because it's cross platform, so I can use it on my Windows and Mac boxes